# Join all p tags XPATH Power Automate

Tags: xml, xpath, power-automate

Been struggling with a flow to add rows in excel from html table.

I've followed this guide from youtube [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4GHCGMAD88)
and it works with the first p tag
But i want to join all ptags to same string.

This will iterate through all items and retrieve the first p[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4GHCGMAD88), next iteration p[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM6mh.png) and so on..
"xpath(xml(outputs('XMLHTML')), concat('//table[.1]//tr[.2]//td[.1]//p[',item(),']//text()'))?[0]"

But in my case it looks like this
[image: Select flow in power automate]

`<p class="MsoNormal"> <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:11.0pt; color:black; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">GLU900 L700/800/1800</span> <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:11.0pt; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">/2100/2600/2602 ;</span> <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:11.0pt; color:black; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">5G ;</span> <span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:11.0pt; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">3<span style="color:black"> sector</span></span> </p>`

[image: picture]

[image]

"//table[.1]//tr[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM6mh.png)//td[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USqLP.png)//p[.1]//text()"

And i will only retrieve the first item.
I want to join all 5 element to same string and then iterate through the next set of p tags

this is what i've found, but I dont know how to iterate through this when its not ending with a text() function in xpath
**xpath(xml(outputs('XMLHTML')), 'string(//table[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4GHCGMAD88)//tr[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM6mh.png)//td[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USqLP.png)//p[',item(),'])')?[0]**

Error Message

> The execution of template action 'Select' failed: The evaluation of
> 'query' action 'where' expression '{ "FuncID":
> "@xpath(xml(outputs('XMLHTML')),
> concat('//table[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4GHCGMAD88)//tr[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM6mh.png)//td[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4GHCGMAD88)//p[',item(),']//text()'))?[0]",
> "SiteName": "@xpath(xml(outputs('XMLHTML')),
> concat('//table[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4GHCGMAD88)//tr[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM6mh.png)//td[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM6mh.png)//p[',item(),']//text()'))?[0]",
> "Technology": "@xpath(xml(outputs('XMLHTML')),
> 'string(//table[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4GHCGMAD88)//tr[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM6mh.png)//td[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USqLP.png)//p[',item(),'])')?[0]", "Comment":
> "@xpath(xml(outputs('XMLHTML')),
> concat('//table[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4GHCGMAD88)//tr[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM6mh.png)//td[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFmE5.png)//p[',item(),']//text()'))?[0]" }'
> failed: 'The template language function 'xpath' expects two
> parameters: an XML object and an XPath expression. The function was
> invoked with '4' parameter(s). Please see
> https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#xpath for usage details.'.

So, at the end
How do i concatenate all 5 elements in list of p-tags to one line and how do i iterate through the elements in power automate??

```
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="939"
style="width:703.95pt; margin-left:.1pt; border-collapse:collapse">
<tbody>
    <tr style="height:15.75pt">
        <td width="54" nowrap=""
            style="width:40.8pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 3.5pt 0cm 3.5pt; height:15.75pt">
            <p class="MsoNormal"><b><span
                        style="font-size:11.0pt; color:black; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">FuncID</span></b>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td width="197" nowrap=""
            style="width:147.45pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 3.5pt 0cm 3.5pt; height:15.75pt">
            <p class="MsoNormal"><b><span
                        style="font-size:11.0pt; color:black; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">SiteName</span></b>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td width="485" nowrap=""
            style="width:364.1pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 3.5pt 0cm 3.5pt; height:15.75pt">
            <p class="MsoNormal"><b><span
                        style="font-size:11.0pt; color:black; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">Technology</span></b>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td width="202" nowrap=""
            style="width:151.6pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none; padding:0cm 3.5pt 0cm 3.5pt; height:15.75pt">
            <p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style="font-size:11.0pt; color:black">Comments</span></b></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:43.4pt">
        <td width="54" nowrap=""
            style="width:40.8pt; border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none; padding:0cm 3.5pt 0cm 3.5pt; height:43.4pt">
            <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt">T223566</span></p>
            <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt">T335125</span></p>
            <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11.0pt">T311000</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width="197" nowrap=""
            style="width:147.45pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 3.5pt 0cm 3.5pt; height:43.4pt">
            <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:11.0pt">Testing1 test1 test1</span></p>
            <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:11.0pt">Testing2 test2 test2</span></p>
            <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US">Testing 3 test3 test3</span></p>
        </td>
        <td width="485" nowrap=""
            style="width:364.1pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 3.5pt 0cm 3.5pt; height:43.4pt">
            <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US">GLU900 L700/800/1800/2100/2600/2602 5G 4 Sec</span>tor<span
                    lang="EN-US"></span></p>
            <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US">&nbsp;</span></p>
            <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US"
                    style="font-size:11.0pt; color:black; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">GLU900
                    L700/800/1800</span><span lang="EN-US"
                    style="font-size:11.0pt; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">/2100/2600/2602
                    &nbsp;</span><span lang="EN-US"
                    style="font-size:11.0pt; color:black; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">5G
                    &nbsp;</span><span lang="EN-US"
                    style="font-size:11.0pt; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">5</span><span lang="EN-US"
                    style="font-size:11.0pt; color:black; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm"> sector</span>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td width="202" nowrap=""
            style="width:151.6pt; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 3.5pt 0cm 3.5pt; height:43.4pt">
            <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US"
                    style="font-size:11.0pt; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">&nbsp;</span></p>
            <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US"
                    style="font-size:11.0pt; color:black; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">5G will be
                    activated tomorrow</span></p>
            <p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US" style="font-size:11.0pt">3-D</span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

BR Erik

Update Flow

[image]
[image]

Result from "select" flow
[image]

Original email
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm really confused.  I think I know what you want but can you please just show the exact output you want from the XML you provided?

Comment: The part //table[1]//tr2//td3//p[1] contains the string 
"GLU900 L700/800/1800 /2100/2600/2602 5G 3 sector"
but in order to loop this in my select loop in power automate have to use the XPATH text() function to extract the string and when I use Xpath //table[1]//tr2//td3//p[1]//text() i'll get a list and only the first item is extracted:
1. GLU900 L700/800/1800
2. /2100/2600/2602
3. 5G
4. 3
5. sector
I want to join all items in list with the text() function.

Comment: In Select action in my flow a use this expression: 
xpath(xml(outputs('XMLHTML')), concat('//table[1]//tr[2]//td[3]//p[',item(),']//text()'))?[0]
 ,with no problem except that it only takes the first item in the list.

I want it to work with 
xpath(xml(outputs('XMLHTML')), 'string(//table[1]//tr[2]//td[1]//p[',item(),']))')?[0]
,And i dont understand why it doesnt work.

Or if i can use some other kind of expression in xpath with text() to get all items joined together.

Comment: I assume you have many <p> elements, would that be right?  If so, can you provide a more complex HTML example so I can build the flow for it?

Comment: I really appreciate you trying, i've edited the post with the complete html table.

Comment: Ok, just so I'm clear ... for all of those <p> elements, you want to extract them individually and then concatenate all text within each individual <p> element together?  Am I right?

Comment: I want to concatenate all text in all<span tag within the same p tag.
<p class="MsoNormal"><span lang="EN-US"
                    style="font-size:11.0pt; color:black; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">GLU900
                    L700/800/1800</span><span lang="EN-US"
                    style="font-size:11.0pt; border:none windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm">/2100/2600/2602
                    &nbsp;</span><span lang="EN-US"
For example, theese 2 span tags within the same <p tag should result in one string:
GLU900 L700/800/1800/2100/2600/2602

Comment: Yep, ok, that’s basically what I was intimating. Leave it with me.

Comment: What should  this part `[',item(),']` in your XPath do?

Comment: [',item(),'] is a range from 1 to "number of rows in my table". It will iterate over all <p> tags and in my xpath querry i will fetch //table[1]//tr[2]//td[3]//p[1].. //p[2].. //p[3] and so on

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to make it work, I had to remove the `&nbsp;` data from your HTML, it didn't like it.  See how you go though.

There are a few options for your XPath query, it all depends on the specifics of what you want to achieve.  Try these for example ...

**`//p/span/text()`**

```
T223566
T335125
T311000
Testing1 test1 test1
Testing2 test2 test2
Testing 3 test3 test3
GLU900 L700/800/1800/2100/2600/2602 5G 4 Sec
```

**`//p/descendant::*/text()`**

```
FuncID

                    

                        
SiteName

                    

                        
Technology

                    

                        
Comments

                    
T223566
T335125
T311000
Testing1 test1 test1
Testing2 test2 test2
Testing 3 test3 test3
GLU900 L700/800/1800/2100/2600/2602 5G 4 Sec
```

Depending on which one you choose, they will return an array of values and by the looks if it, it will ignore all of the blank rows.

I tested with the second XPath query in my flow which yielded the following result ...

[image: Result]

This was the step after initializing a variable which contained your HTML data (again, removing the `&nbsp;` values though) ...

```
xpath(xml(variables('XML')), '//p/descendant::*/text()')
```

Comment: Yes, i've managed to come this far but for some reason the string "GLU900 L700/800/1800/2100/2600/2602 5G 4 Sec" is inside same <p>-and <span> tag. next <p> tag in code have almost the same string "L700/800/1800<span>/2100/2600/2602<span> 5G <span>5 <span>Sector" where it is divided by multiple <span> tags. This is what i want to concatenate to one string

Comment: You’ll need to show the results of your flow to help me. Also, just confirm, you get that result from my expression or your own? Because you can see the output mine provides so if you get a different result to me, either the expression isn’t quite right or your HTML is different to what you provided. It should produce the same result.

Comment: I've pasted everything in my flow and the results in the original post

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply, been very busy at work.  I got very close by using a different approach but still have more work to do.  I can't get the underlying texts to come through as a single text string, it comes out as an array.  LogicApps doesn't have an Excel like formula to perform text joins from an array.  Would be handy if it did.

Comment: Ok, I have an answer for you but you won't be able to use PowerAutomate, you'd need to switch to using LogicApps in Azure Portal.  PA runs off the LogicApps engine but, it's a shift and probably not what you want to do.

Comment: … or alternatively, you’ll need two flows in PowerAutomate to break it up and make it manageable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at HTML, so I convert the file to PDF, and use AI Builder to read the PDF file content and it's working well for me, maybe you can try it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).